# Changing dataframe value based on next occurrence using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to solve the following problem. I have a code where there is an event and it is connected to a time in seconds. I am attaching this to video so I need a lead and a lag time. I am able to create the lead time, but for some of the events, the lag time is correlated to when the next event occurs.

For example, a shot has a lead time of 3 and a lag time of 7. However, for zone time, I need to create a lead time of 3 and a lag time of next occurrence of the title 'whistle'.

Comment: so you have a video, you are adding a time on it, once some text event is occurring you have to put the time back , so you are not able to catch the text event of the time..??

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: So you are able to identify that event successfully, then I will share the code to get time and time difference